# Get line break from UITextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, text, uitextview

I'm building a small messaging app for the `iPhone`. When the user writes a message in my `UITextView` I save it to an online `database`. Then I download that and display it to another user. The problem is that the string that I send to the `DB` do not include the "\n"-sign from the `Uitextview` that the user typed in, When I try to display the message it displays it in one line instead of the formatting the user inputed.

I somehow want to get all newline-signs from the `UitextView` and save them inside the text in the DB so I can display the message with the right formatting.

How do I do this in Objective C?

Answer (score 3):

`UITextView` supports the `'\n'` newline, and its `text` property will contains them.

You can try this to confirm that a `UITextView` supports them (note that `textView` is a `UITextView`):

```
if ([self.textView.text rangeOfString:@"\n"].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"newline found");
}
```

Or this

```
self.textView.text = @"new\nline";
```

So may be you problem is elsewhere in the code that persist the user string.